# Nmap program not found in path

Tags: python-3.x, nmap

I am trying to use nmap in my script for which have installed python-nmap. But when using with portscanner then it returns error as nmap program not found. I tried setting up variable and different suggestion given at community.

Still an facing the same issue. Request team to please help me on this

[Image for bash where it clearly state that path is set still it returns as path not set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvppv.png)

[checked path as well as the nmap is there or not and yes it is available there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ntA7.png)

Comment: Does python-nmap install a copy of nmap? I would not be surprised if it did not.

Comment: Yes nmap copy is already there